# Remove SendOnBehalfOf recipient from a Reply To All

Tags: vba, outlook

I am using multiple accounts and often send on behalf of other accounts. When using "Reply to All" I will send a copy to the account I am sending from.

To prevent this, I have the following code in the newItem_Open - sub:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To newItem.Recipients.Count
    If newItem.Recipients(i).Name = newItem.SentOnBehalfOfName Then newItem.Recipients.Remove i
Next i
```

If the SendOnBehalfOf-recipient is not the last recipient, on the last recipient I get an error, as the "Count" is still on the original number, but in fact the recipients are one less already.

How can I deal with this, I think I would have to reset the Count, but how?

Thanks 
MAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I can't really reproduce the scenario, I guess a quick workaround is sth like this

```
Dim i As Long
Dim currentTotal As long
currentTotal = newItem.Recipients.Count
For i = 1 To newItem.Recipients.Count
    If (i <= currentTotal) then
        If newItem.Recipients(i).Name = newItem.SentOnBehalfOfName Then 
           newItem.Recipients.Remove i
           currentTotal = currentTotal - 1
        End If
    'Exit the subroutine if i > total no. of recipients at the moment
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: thanks for the Input, I made it similar and it works perfect. Only difference is that I restart the procedure if i > current total, as otherwise it might happen that not all items are checked. see my code in next comment

Comment: Dim i As Long

restart:

For i = 1 To newItem.Recipients.Count

    If i > newItem.Recipients.Count Then GoTo restart

    If newItem.Recipients(i).Name = newItem.SentOnBehalfOfName Then 

newItem.Recipients.Remove i

Next i

Comment: glad to know it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Count backward when deleting or moving.

The index keeps changing so you skip items. (Same problem with a For Each loop.)

```
For i = newItem.Recipients.Count to 1 step - 1
If newItem.Recipients(i).Name = newItem.SentOnBehalfOfName Then
    newItem.Recipients.Remove i
End If 
Next i
```